# CoreDNS service Corefile location

Tags: kubernetes, dns, coredns

I would like to view the configuration file of  CoreDNS service.

When i look in to the coredns deployment file it is shown as

```
  spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - -conf
    - /etc/coredns/Corefile
    image: k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

- Is the /etc/coredns/Corefile  inside the container
- If yes,How to view it.. i am unable to get in to the coredns container
- If i change the coredns config map file, will the /etc/coredns/Corefile also change

[image: Coredns pods]

[image: Unable to get in to coredns pod]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically Corefile is included in coredns which is a  kind of ConfigMap in Kubernetes.

1. To view it you have to check ConfigMap resourse.

```
kubectl get ConfigMap coredns -n kube-system -o yaml
```

2.If you change coredns ConfigMap data Corefile then /etc/cordns/Corefile will be changed also.you can check this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
            ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

Comment: 1)  if i want to see the Corefile, where should i view it
2)  Location /etc/coredns/Corefile is in master node or in the container

Comment: it will in the coredns container but you can not be able to see by using kubectl exec.So Please check the coredns configMap and edit to change the corefile.

Comment: To clarify the last point, `kubectl edit ConfigMap coredns -n kube-system` to change